# Show totalDistance from L.Routing.control at every route change?

Tags: leaflet, jquery

I need to insert the calculation of the distance of my route in the input to show the user.
I need this to happen when the page loads and when the user adds or removes a bookmark.
I tried in different ways, but I couldn't.

Follow the code below:

```
var r_ida = L.Routing.control({
            show: true,
            geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
            autoRoute: true,
            waypoints: way_ida,
            router: new L.Routing.osrmv1({
                serviceUrl: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:5000/route/v2',
            }),
            routeWhileDragging: true,
            collapsible: true,
            lineOptions: {
                styles: [{ color: "blue", opacity: 1 }],
            },
            createMarker: function (i, wp, nWps) {
                var marker = L.marker(wp.latLng, {
                    pane: 'routingMarkersIda',
                    shadowPane: 'routingMarkersShadowIda',
                    draggable: true,
                    icon: criandoNumeracao(i, nWps)
                });
                return marker;
            },
        }).addTo(map);

$(document).mousemove(function() {
     r_ida.on('routesfound', function(e) {
        var routes = e.routes;
        var summary = routes[0].summary;
        console.log(summary.totalDistance / 1000);
        $('km-volta').val(summary.totalDistance / 1000);
     });
});

<input type="text" id="km-ida"/>
```

I created a simulation of something similar to exemplify https://jsfiddle.net/Douglaslf/a1shgtp5/21/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes no sense to catch every `mousemove` event and then again and again define `routesfound` catching function. Just `routesfound` will suffice:

```
r_ida.on('routesfound', function(e) {
  var routes = e.routes;
  var summary = routes[0].summary;
  console.log(summary.totalDistance / 1000);
  document.getElementById('km-ida').value = (summary.totalDistance / 1000);
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/hp86ntmj/.